# Listings Keyword Can't Be Removed

Tags: listings

I have the following sample of code.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[
       language=SQL,
       showspaces=false,
       basicstyle=\ttfamily,
       numbers=left,
       numberstyle=\tiny,
       commentstyle=\color{gray},
       keywords={}
    ]
SELECT * FROM date;
\end{lstlisting}
```

Even though I have removed all keywords using keywords={}, date is still being highlighted as a keyword.

Any idea why?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do you need `deletekeywords`?

Comment: I have tried `deletekeywords={date}`, though it still has no effect

Comment: Try this: `keywords={},keywords={[2]{}}`

Comment: thank you! `keywords={[2]{}}` works

Comment: @hair-splitter Can you elaborate the solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

`keywords={}` delete (more exactly redefine) the all keywords from keyword list 1. The `DATE` keyword is in the keyword list 2. So you should delete the all keywords from keyword list 2 with `keywords={[2]}` or `keywords={[2]{}}`. If you want to delete only `DATE` keyword, then use `deletekeywords={[2]DATE}`.